# convert csv to excel with space delimeter

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I have csv file with delimeter space of following format.

```
1 26/APR/2014 15:49:07 9421131317 21:28 6.60 **
2 26/APR/2014 16:10:57 9421131317 07:51 2.40 **
```

I want to convert it in excel file, so that i will get every record in separate cell. I have tried various online tool to convert it to excel but they are converted into single cell.

Is there any way to convert date, time , mobile number in separate cell using excel.

Comment: you can write a Program in C#/Java to convert it to ',' CSV file

or copy/replace `space` with `,` in some editor like `notepad` or `wordpad`

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior If the format is the given in the example, that's overkill.

Comment: @Pablo I had missed the easy method. Update my comment now

Comment: Thanks for response. Since i am working on VDI, i have only access of browsers, MS Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let Excel figure out the datatypes without any code. Try this:

1. Open the csv file with Excel
2. Select column A
3. Go to Data > Text to columns
4. Choose Delimited > Next
5. Choose Space and unselect the rest
6. Press Finish

Video on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neDUOYk8hyU)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text editor (Notepad++, for example) to replace spaces by commas and then you'll have a classic CSV file, which can be directly opened by Excel. It allows even regular expressions when searching and replacing text.

UPDATE: You can do the same with the "build-in" editor of you system, if you cannot download anything. Notepad on Windows can replace spaces by commas as well.